# Combine field_weights with ORDER by in Sphinx

Tags: union, sphinx

I seem to have had my [question answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032231/select-union-in-sphinxql/43044200?noredirect=1#comment73227636_43044200) on how to order results by relevance using `OPTION field_weights`. However I'm finding it does not work when using an `ORDER by` in the same `SphinxQL` Query e.g.

`Select * from Items where MATCH('@(Listing_Title) London @(Listing_Title,Description) Jack') ORDER By Featured_Flag DESC OPTION field_weights=(Author=1000)`

Which basically is trying to say:

"Find me all the books with 'Jack' and 'London', put all the books by featured sellers first and non-features sellers after, and in each group put the records where both 'Jack' and 'London' appear in the Listing_Title itself"

So a sample return should look like this where the field order is:

```
Listing_Title                Description                      Featured_Flag

Jack London Books for Sale   New buy now!                     1
London, Steinbeck and more   Call of the Wild by Jack London  1
Jack London Classics!        In great shape write or call     0
Call of Wild - London        THE Jack London                  0
```

Once I add the `ORDER by Featured_Flag DESC` however the `field_weights=(Listing_Title=1000)` is no longer obeyed.

Is there some other way to do this? I've read that querying two indexes can act as a union perhaps a Listing_Title_Index and a All_Index would work?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `field_weights` just modify the computed weight (giving extra weight to specific field(s). So need to ensure that `WEIGHT()` is still factored into your ORDER BY somehow.

If there is **no** `ORDER BY` (and there is a `MATCH(...)`) then sphinx will *automatically* order by `WEIGHT()`, but if supply a sort order, need to add it yourself

For example:

```
... ORDER By Featured_Flag DESC, WEIGHT() DESC
```

Comment: Yeah after adding `Weight()` to the select i noticed that (and it is always the weight of the current weighting so adding a `field_weights1 changes `Weight()`. Once I figured that out I just add to manually add the Weight() to the Order so that I could combine it with other field orders.